# Model.find_by_sql vs connection.query, which one is better?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In rails-

I need to execute a sql query against the database; the query is not related to any specific Model it can have mix data from multiple tables or from some other table. I have ways to do this=-

- first is by executing query agains Model and capture the result like this-

  1. res=User.find_by_sql("select * from customers joins and conditions")
  2. res=User.find_by_sql("select * from [other table] joins and conditions")

Problem with this approach, I am not feeling comfortable with it because in User class objects I am capturing data of other table. like the first query result has data from customer table so in the user object I got customer's attribute. And more interesting problem is- if the resulting query has id attribute then

res.first.id will be id of customer and 
if User model has relation with UserRoles model and if I access this relation with res.first.roles then it will fetch roles from UserRole for customer id, which is completely wrong.

And there might be may problems also.

So I think it has lot of chaos.

And good part is we dont not need to deal with connection and result would be an array of objects. so accessing object attributes with res.first.id is easier the hast like row["id"].

- and second approach to use ActiveRecord connection and execute the query like

this `res = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.query("sql query")`
in place of query we can use select_one, select_all and can also make query parameterized.

The problem it has is it returns array of hash, but I need array of objects for easy accessibility in code. So I wrote a class to convert hash to object (I think rail does same thing in background) and is working fine.

So I need some suggestion on both the approach and need to decide which one is better.

Comment: Have you tried with joins and includes for this type of queries?

Comment: if you mean User.join(:table) this then, we need to execute sql only. Not to use join on rails model.

Comment: You should try building the query using the joins method. For Ex: Customer.joins(:model_name).where(some_condition)

Comment: I don't have predefined queries as I said the query can be on any table. So can't use join on models, this is not an option here for sure. I know about it very well but cant use it here. We already have lots sql query which we want to execute and get data.

Comment: Are you doing an app where user can execute queries to the db?

Comment: @Michael- here we are sending mail to users. and to extract users list for different mail types we have different sql queries(500+). so we are looking for a generic solution where we can execute these existing queries to get data (users or other information).

Comment: You would have to be more specific about what you're trying to achieve. Sounds rather complicates, even over-complicated I would say.

Comment: Its a mailing system. I have a table which contains template_name and sql_query (these are two main for this problem), there is task which iterates over this table data and send sends mail to users. So each row represents a mail to some users. the template_name (erb file name) is what we want to render in mail body and sql_query is the data which we push to view context to generate appropriate body content. So we need to execute the sql_query against the database, this is where I raised this question. And I think there are 500+ rows in this table. –

Answer (score 3):

**First find_by_sql vs select_all**

***find_by_sql***, This method returns an array of objects by initiating them.

```
users = User.find_by_sql("SELECT * FROM users"); #=>  [#, #, #, # ....]


Accessing properties
users[0].name   #Getting property in object oriented fashion
```

***select_all***, This method returns an array of objects but does not initiate them, and each object represents a row of database.

```
users = User.connection.select_all("SELECT * FROM users"); #=>  #

Accessing properties
users[0]["name"] #Getting property in non-object oriented fashion
```

Whether find_by_sql is better, because of it is a simple way of custom querying to the database and returns instantiated objects